# How to insert the data in the newly created column in the dataset in C#

Tags: c#

I have loaded .csv file into the dataset. The csv file(have afew hundreds lines) format is as follow;

```
"UCPTlogTime","UCPTpointName","UCPTvalue","UCPTunit"
2010-07-05T11:08:07.390+08:00,"Net/LON/wattnode1/VirtFb/nvoCurrent[0]","0.128767","Amperes"
2010-07-05T11:08:10.720+08:00,"Net/LON/wattnode1/VirtFb/nvoPower[0]","28.90336","Watts"
2010-07-05T11:08:11.680+08:00,"Net/LON/wattnode1/VirtFb/nvoCurrent[0]","0.128767","Amperes"
2010-07-05T11:08:18.830+08:00,"Net/LON/wattnode1/VirtFb/nvoPower[0]","34.48953","Watts"
```

As u can see, in the UCPTvalue column, two different type of datas are saved.
What i want to do is before updating the remote server with all those data, i want to seperate the Amperes data and Watts data in the individual column. Is there any C# code to create the new column in dataset and set it with the data from existing column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use datasets, myself. I'd bulk load it into a temp database table, then update the relevant tables for each UCPT unit type (in other words, do it all in a stored procedure).

**[edited for more detail]**

Create a new table called tmpUpdate.

SQLBulkCopy the data into it.

Then run a stored proc that does multiple updates using it, eg something like

```
update liveTable set latestAmps=tempUpdate.UCPTvalue
FROM liveAmpTable JOIN tempUpdate ON liveAmpTable.UCPTpointName=tempUpdate.UCPTpointName
WHERE tempUpdate.UCPTunit='Amperes'

update liveTable set latestWatts=tempUpdate.UCPTvalue
FROM liveWattsTable JOIN tempUpdate ON liveWattsTable.UCPTpointName=tempUpdate.UCPTpointName
WHERE tempUpdate.UCPTunit='Watts'

truncate table tempUpdate --clear temp data
```

This assumes only one user does the updating at the same time.

Comment: Hi,
could you tell me more details cos i'm just start learning. currently, i'm using dataTableReader, dataSet and SQLbulkCopy to update the remote SQL database. My initial idea is to edit the table before sending to database by using buldcopy.